# Set highlight in vim function

Tags: search, highlight

I am trying to highlight a word in the current buffer dynamically like so:

```
function! Highlight()

  let @/ = 'word'
  set hlsearch

endfunction
```

When I run this function, the register `/` contains `word` as desired but the word `word` is not highlighted.

This surprises me because if I remove the `set hlsearch` part and after the function runs, I call it manually, it highlight correctly the word.

What can I do to have the correct behavior?

Comment: `:h function-search-undo`

Comment: You can add a execute function like `exe '/'` before set highlight

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt does that mean it's not possible to keep the search highlight on with functions ? (in that case I guess I'll create a new highlight pattern to achieve the same effect)

Comment: @nobe4 you can make the function return the actual commands. That should work.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt: I tried returning `"set hlsearch"`, then both commands `"let @/ = 'word' | set hlsearch"`, but it does not seems to work. You idea is interesting, do you know where I can find example/doc about this ?

Comment: @Nobe4: when we save a value to search register, it just gets stored. Only when you search it is highlighted, else it isn't. When you set highlight, it means that hereafter all searches will be highlighted. Without searching it will not be highlighted at all. Just because putting the two statements next to each other, how will it highlight the word. I hope you know this very well. May I know what you wanted to do?

Comment: @SibiCoder: I want to do no more than what is explained in my question (that is highlighting a word from a vim function). As for the issue, I think ChristianBrabandt pointed a possible explanation.

Comment: @SibiCoder setting `@/` will highlight matches.

Comment: @nobe4 Works for me. Maybe something else is interfering.

Comment: @Antony: It does not for me, even with `vim -Nu NONE`. The comment from Christian Brabandt reference the reason why it's not supposed to highlight...

Comment: @nobe4 Ah, I tried it with `vim -u NONE`. It works like that.

Comment: @Antony What do you mean it works? Does `'word'` gets highlighted if you call `Highligth()`? Because it should not... Strange.

Comment: Yeah, works as intended if I start with `vim -u NONE`. Doesn't if I start with `vim -Nu NONE`, even if I then `:set compatible`. Bug? Vim 7.4.778 btw.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41145/discussion-between-nobe4-and-antony).

Comment: You can get around this with `call feedkeys(":setlocal hls\r", 'n')`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A workaround:

```
function! Highlight()

  call matchadd('error', 'word')

endfunction
```

The `matchadd` function takes an highlight group (here `'error'`) and a regex to match (here `'word'`), it will create a new highlight a return it's ID.

---

**Bonus:**

If you want to change the highlight over time, you can store this ID, call `matchdelete(ID)` to clear the current highlight and call `matchadd` again to add a new highlight.

e.g. pressing `<C-H>` will highlight the word under the cursor:

```
let s:current_matching = -1

function! Highlight()

  if s:current_matching != -1
    call matchdelete(s:current_matching)
  endif
  let s:current_matching = matchadd('error', expand('<cword>'))

endfunction

nnoremap <C-H> :call Highlight()<CR>
```

Answer (score 0):

For reference, and maybe further research:

After a long discussion with [antony](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/7878/antony) we found out that this behavior is enable in compatible mode but not in nocompatible mode.

i.e. the code will highlight when called from

```
vim -u NONE
```

but not from

```
vim -Nu NONE
```

Moreover, we found that setting `hls` and `nohls` one after the other will make the highlight work for both `compatible` and `nocompatible`.

e.g. this code correctly highlight for both `compatible` and `nocompatible`:

```
function! Highlight()
  let @/ = 'word'
  set hlsearch
endfunction

let @/=''
set hls
set nohls

" source %
" call Highlight()
```